# Do peewee models automatically close the connection?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, peewee

I am using peewee to access a SQLite DB.

I have made a `model.py` like:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()
    is_relative = BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

In another Python file (with `import model`) I then manipulate the DB with calls like `Person.create()` or `Person.select(name=='Joe').delete_instance()`.

The [Quickstart](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html) says at the end to call `db.close()` to close the connection. Does this apply to my case as well? Am I supposed to call something like `model.db.close()`?

Comment: may i know what is_relative attribute will do(what's the use of it)...??

Answer (score 10):

According to [Charles Leifer](https://github.com/coleifer), the maker of peewee, **it is the programmer's job to terminate connections**. The documentation about Connection Pools tells that all connections are thread-local, so as long as the Model is in use, the connection stays open, and dies when the thread containing the Transaction joins the Main-Thread.

Charles explicitly answers a question about the Connection Pool. The answer is a bit generalized, but I suppose this applies to all connections equally: [About connection pool](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/1143#issuecomment-266308713)

Implicit answers on the topic:

[Error 2006: MySQL server has gone away](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html?highlight=Connection#error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Excerpt from the docs [Quickstart Page](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html?highlight=close%20connection#quickstart):

> Although it’s not necessary to open the connection explicitly, it is good practice since it will reveal any errors with your database connection immediately, as opposed to some arbitrary time later when the first query is executed. **It is also good to close the connection when you are done** – for instance, a web app might open a connection when it receives a request, and close the connection when it sends the response.

The final answer to your question is, based on these information: No.

Answer (score 3):

You open and close the connection manually:

In your case (with `db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')`)

you established connection with the database by:

```
db.connect()
```

next you do whatever you want with the database and finally you close the connection with:

```
db.close()
```